# Utiliser "à" devant un nom qui commence par "À ..." ou "Au ..." ou "Chez ..."

Tags: prépositions, noms-propres

Si on imagine un restaurant (il en existe sûrement beaucoup) qui s'appelle "À la bonne fourchette", et que je veux dire à mes amis qu'on se retrouve là bas, dois-je leur dire :

- On se retrouve À la bonne fourchette.
- On se retrouve à À la bonne fourchette.
- Autre chose ?

---

La même question pourrait se poser pour "Chez Franquette" :

- On se retrouve Chez Franquette.
- On se retrouve à Chez Franquette.
- Autre chose ?

---

Ou pour "Au ventre bien rempli" :

- On se retrouve Au ventre bien rempli
- On se retrouve à Au ventre bien rempli
- Autre chose ?

Comment: Bonne question. Anecdotiquement mais tout-à-fait dans le sujet, on peut noter qu'à Metz, il y a (*avait* ? je ne sais pas s'il existe encore) un restaurant appelé *« Chez moi »*, et à Nancy il y en a un qui s'appelle *« Chez Elle »*. Je vous laisse imaginer les incommunications et éclaircissements nécessaires...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dans les trois cas, il ne faut pas rajouter de "à", car il est incorrect de mettre 2 prépositions à la suite. Ainsi, "à", "au" ou "chez" deviennent des prépositions en plus d'être une partie du nom du restaurant. Pour ne pas laisser d’ambiguïté, il faudrait dire "On se retrouve au restaurant Chez Franquette", par exemple.

Il faut également rajouter "le" à la liste: un restaurant s'appelant "Le Pub" donnerait "On se retrouve au Pub".

Answer (score 4):

Le plus raisonnable est dans bien des cas de rendre la chose explicite :

> On se retrouve au restaurant « À la bonne fourchette ».

Cela fonctionne aussi bien pour les restaurants à préposition que pour les restaurants sans préposition.

Cela dit, si l'interlocuteur est familier du lieu, la bonne idée c'est de jouer le jeu en n'utilisant pas un nom propre mais l'expression qu'il suggère.

> On se retrouve à la bonne fourchette ? ou bien chez Franquette ?

Autrement, le nom du restaurant ne s'y prêtant pas, il vaut mieux éviter l'approche directe, car à l'oral elle ne laisse le choix qu'entre une double préposition — certainement un peu moche — ou une ambiguïté — qui peut rendre le restaurant plus difficile à localiser… Bien entendu, certains n'auront aucun mal à choisir, il préfèreront sacrifier leur soirée plutôt que leur français ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> On se retrouve [*au* restaurant] "À la bonne fourchette".

On sous-entend « au restaurant » dans cette phrase, pour éviter la redondance.

Il y a d'autres possibilités, selon la qualité des lieux :

> On se retrouve :
>
> - sur les Champs[-Élysées], (lieu unique)
> - chez Maxim's, (restaurant très connu près des Champ-Élysées dont le nom est un prénom)
> - rue de la soif (car on sait à quel numéro on a l'habitude de se retrouver)